# ajax call failing

Tags: ajax, jquery, json

On the same page I have 2 sections. First section is generated dynamically (when I enter a text in an autocomplete field) and the second section is loaded on pageload.

There is an ajax all I need to make from both sections (basically add a product button is present in both sections).

```
jq.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(); ?>marketplace/product/addcart/',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {"productid":product_id,"qty":product_qty,"customOption":customOption}, 
      success: function(result) {
                jq('.ajax_loader').hide();
                var cartdiv = result.cartsidebar;                     
                jq(".shoping-cart").html(cartdiv);
                jq.growl.notice({ message: result.message });

                              }

});
```

This call succeeds from the second section and works like a charm but when I make the same call from the first section (that was dynamically generated) then it fails and xrs.status is 0

I have checked in firebug and the url is resolving exactly the same in both sections:

```
GET http://localhost/magentonew/marketplace/product/addcart/?productid=5666&qty=1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you are missing the form key.
Try to make the `data` option for the ajax call look like this:

```
{"productid":product_id,"qty":product_qty,"customOption":customOption,"form_key":FORM_KEY}
```

Comment: sorry did not work... i added var FORM_KEY = '<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey(); ?>'; and then your code